# Extracting the first row of every column having multiple base rows

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, awk

For example:

```
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST
        inetasdfsd fdsfdsf sdfdsf 
        asfdsa dafdsg sfgfsg sgsgd
dockerApps: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  
           inet dsfsdf sdfds sdfdsf 
           inetdfdsf sdgdsg gdsgdsg sdgds 

ens192: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST
       inet sfsf sf sf sf sf sf s
       inedfs sf s sffs fsf sf s
```

What I want is:

```
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST
dockerApps: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST> 
ens192: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST
```

and so on, not only corresponding of above three, based on the output of ifconfig, need to capture interface status, all it has

*Help
printing $1 gives

```
docker0:
dockerApps:
ens192:
```

Comment: If you [edit] your question to explain what you actually want to capture ("_need to capture interface status_" doesn't explain which bit you really want), it might be just as easy for someone to provide a complete solution rather than just the partial one you've asked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to print all the lines that don't start with a space, you can use

```
grep '^[^ ]'
```

If it's space or tab, you can use a POSIX class:

```
grep '^[^[:space:]]'
```

The first `^` means *beginning of a line*, the outer `[]` introduces a character class. The `^` inside a character class negates it, so it matches *all characters except for the listed ones*. `[:space:]` matches any whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

```
ifconfig | awk '/docker|ens192/{print $0}'
```

Kindly use above command as I tested it and it worked fine.